# Can't build ASP.NET Core app that references PCL in docker

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, portable-class-library

I am trying to build an ASP.NET Core docker image with following Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.1.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY src .
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish --output /out/ --configuration Release
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","/out/MyWebApp.dll"]
```

The build fails, and it gives the following error:

*/app/MyPCL/MyPCL.csproj(70,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.1/Microsoft/Portable/v4.5/Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.*

So it is having trouble building the PCL library, as it can't find Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets.

My PCL project file has the following import statement:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Portable\$(TargetFrameworkVersion)\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" />
```

which I am thinking is causing the problem, as this path must not exist in the docker container. BTW, the project builds and runs perfectly in Visual Studio 2017.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you confusing PCL with Application? ASP.NET Core application are also in a dll, but it's technically not a "PCL", since a) ASP.NET Core (on .NET Core) targets `netcoreapp1.1` which means it can only run there and not on i.e. .NET Framework or Windows Mobile, so it runs only on a single platform and b) the "application dll" has an entry point (a `Main` method), PCL doesn't, so you are most likely having a wrong target. Do not target `netstandardx.y`, but target `netcoreappx.y` instead. With `dotnet run` you can only run applications (targeting >=`net45` or `netcoreappx.y`)

Comment: As in my Dockerfile, my "application" is the MyWebApp.dll, which is an ASP.NET Core application, which targets netcoreapp1.1. I have a library project "MyPCL" which the web app is referencing, which is a portable class library which is targeting PCL profile111. My understanding is that currently dotnet is not able to build anything other than netcoreapp at this stage. But I feel it should be able to build portable class libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this is not possible yet, but they are working on it:

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5504

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25063/building-running-publishing-a-aspnet-core-net-fram.html